# Can't find cookie if path is set to /

Tags: java, cookies

Currently using Java I am able to create a cookie and later retrieve it via `Cookie[] browserCookies = request.getCookies();`

The issue comes when I try create a cookie and set its path with `cookie.setPath("/");` I can no longer find it later when the below code.  It has a max age of 30 days so I know it's there and I see it get created but I can't find it any longer after that initial creation.

Here's what I have now which works when not setting a path to "/":

Look for a cookie with a specific name:

```
Cookie[] browserCookies = request.getCookies();
boolean foundCookie = false;

if (browserCookies != null) {
     for (int i =0; i< browserCookies.length; i++) {    
          if ("foo".equalsIgnoreCase(browserCookies[i].getName())) {
               foundCookie = true;
          }
     }
}
```

based on foundCookie, I do something but also based on that I create a new cookie if not found:

```
if (!foundCookie) {
     Cookie fooCookie = new Cookie ("foo", "barValue");

     fooCookie.setMaxAge(30 * 86400);
     //fooCookie.setPath("/"); // If I set this, I can no longer find it later by the name
     response.addCookie(fooCookie);
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Try setting the path to `request.getContextPath()` and see if it works. Your code looks fine to me. Maybe try logging all the cookies and if it does not show up, maybe add domain as well to the cookie and try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SunilChakravarthy I eventually figured out what the issue is.  If I set the path at root / level, in my application the "logout" feature clears the cookies so that's why they weren't found next time.